# Can we migrate questions over from SO yet?

Tags: support

I just tried but moving to the SharePoint stack exchange site was not an option in the "is off topic" pop up window:

[image]

Can we not move these over yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those migration paths won't be defined until the site is out of public beta. If there is dire need, a moderator can move a post, but this should be used very sparingly. We don't want to rush into shuffling posts around the network until the site has a chance to become established and graduates.

Comment: Wondering what is the status of this. I just joined SharePoint stack exchange and I notice a lot of the questions have answers on SO.